# I want to unban someone but it says Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unban')

Tags: discord.js

In discord.js I wrote this code along time ago before the newest version but as I have seen the ban part work (replace .unban with .ban) I thought this would work. Instead I get the error "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unban')"

````js
if (message.content.slice(2).toLowerCase().includes("unban")) {
    if (message.channel.type === 1){
        if (message.content.slice(7).toLowerCase() === ''){
            message.reply({content: 'You can\'t unban blank in a dm' })
        }else{
        message.reply({content: 'you can\'t unban in a dm' })
        }
        return
    }else{
        if (message.content.slice(7).toLowerCase() == ''){

            message.reply({content: 'you can\'t unban no one' })
            return
        }
    }
    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Mod")){
      if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        message.guild.members.unban(member);
        message.channel.send('Unbanned '+ message.content.slice(8))

      }else{
        message.guild.members.cache.get(message.content.slice(8)).unban();
        message.channel.send('Unbanned '+ message.content.slice(8))
        message.delete()
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`⚠️ Error occurred ⚠️ The Error was: 'You dont have "Mod" role'`);

    }
  } ```
````

Comment: Also ban does not work anymore now that the user is not on the server

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your reference to the user fails to resolve properly because the user is banned and therefore not a member of the guild anymore:

`message.guild.members.cache.get(message.content.slice(8))` is undefined because the banned user is not in the guild's cache.

`message.mentions.members.first()` will also not work for unbanning people as you can't mention someone who is not a member of the guild.

An easy way to find and remove the user's ban would be to fetch the list of bans from the server and check for the user there, for example by their user id (or you could loop through the bans and check something else like their name and discriminator, its up to you):

```js
message.guild.bans.fetch().then(bans => {
    if(bans.has(userId)) {
        message.guild.bans.remove(bans.get(userId).user).then((user) => {
            message.channel.send(`Unbanned ${user.username}`);
        }).catch(() => {
            message.channel.send(`Unban failed`);
        });
    } else {
        message.channel.send("There is no ban for this user id.");
    }
});
```

Comment: I got both There is no ban for this user id. and unbanned... because the ```message.channel.send("There is no ban for this user id.");``` is not in a condition but the other part worked. Thanks

Comment: @Bobjoerules my bad, fixed that. I also realized that the bans object is actually a map, so you can check for the user much easier - updated the code to show how!